# Spotify API Authorization Code Flow Returning 'unsupported_grant_type' Error

Tags: node.js, authentication, spotify

I am trying to access the Spotify Web API using a Node.js app. I have specified the `grant_type` as `authorization_code` yet receive an `unsupported_grant_type` error with description `grant_type must be client_credentials, authorization_code or refresh_token`.

As far as I can tell my `post` request is properly formatted and values are all correct. Not sure what else to check.

```
app.post('/auth', (req, res)=>{
  const auth = Buffer
                .from(`${process.env.CLIENT_ID}:${process.env.CLIENT_SECRET}`)
                .toString('base64');
  axios.post(token_uri, {}, {
      params: {
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'code': req.body.code,
      'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
    }, headers: {
        'Authorization': `Basic ${auth}`,
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    })
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the content type correctly, but you are sending the data in JSON format instead of x-www-form-urlencoded format.

The following JSON format

```
      params: {
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'code': 'my_secret_code
    }
```

can be converted to x-www-form-urlencoded like this:

```
params = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=my_secret_code'
```

Try updating your request like this:

```
  const params = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + req.body.code
               + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri
               + '&client_id=' + process.env.CLIENT_ID
               + '&client_secret=' + process.env.CLIENT_SECRET';

  axios.post(token_uri, 
    params,
    {
      headers: {
          'Authorization': `Basic ${auth}`,
          'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    })
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
```